# vue router navigation guard not redirecting after login

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

navigation guard:
[image: navigation guard]

singin function in vuex:
[image: singin function in vuex]

After login it not redirecting to query path. How can i solve this issue.

Comment: hi, welcome to stackoverflow. if you could post well-formatted code instead of screenshot that would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello did you use this "***  this.$router.push('/')  ***".

Comment: In your `else` clause within the navigation guard, provide the path you'd like to redirect to as an argument to the `next()` function like: `next('/some_path')`